# MySQL, Eclipse, and Java - is Ant required?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I am starting my first project with MySQL and Java in Eclipse. I found a tutorial:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/gettingstarted.html

It is full of ant builds and XML files which make me want to explode. Do I really need to use ant builds or can I just import the MySQL driver into my project and import the libraries into the class and away I go? MySQL is already setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are a beginner and just want to learn some Java and MySQL, then Ant is not required. If you are building a project for some class or project. Then Ant is something that you should use. Ant automates your manual steps like compiling and packaging which will become a overhead over a period of time. Ant just manages your build process.

If you are not into build and stuff then happily skip ant. Just add the mysql connector Jar to your classpath and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Ant for development, Eclipse can build your projects just fine.

Once (if) you get into build automation, take a look at Ant again. Before that, you can safely ignore it (as long as you still know how to follow the steps in your tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

Ant is not required for Development, with help of eclipse can build your projects.